# My Kotlin project doesn't create the navigation folder in resources

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack

Hello so I create my android studio project and I select a blank activity. then I select kotlin as the language but I see under res folder and navigation isn't present either the generated java folder.

[image]

it should appear like this...

[image: Correct way!!]

this is my Build.gradle...

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I know someone may answer the logical thing that is you need to add implementation "....."
but what I want is for the android studio once I create a new project that will have the navigation and files necessary to implement jetpack.

Comment: Try clicking the cog in the Project view (at the top), and then ticking "show excluded files"

Comment: I am not aware of any Android Studio template that automatically adds navigation dependencies and a `res/navigation` directory, though I have not tried them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the best way is just do add yourself the navigation pattern.

Here is a link that explains how to do it:
[How to get started with navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)
Also, there is a free udacity course and some codelabs that explain how navigation works.

However, if you really want to get it at a new project from android studio, if you start a new project with **Bottom Navigation Activity** or **Navigation Drawer Activity**, it already has the navigation included.

PS: I don't know if there are any more templates with navigation included because i haven't tried them but *Empty Activity* or *Fragment + ViewModel* doesn't include it.

Comment: Thank you best answer